# Error in syntax, in Access, can not create a form using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```
    Private Sub cmd_creare_Click()

      DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE produse (codpr integer PRIMARY KEY, denpr text(30),
      stoc integer)"
      DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE clienti (codcl integer, dencl text(30),

      PRIMARY KEY(codcl))"

      DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE facturi (nrfact integer PRIMARY KEY, datfact date,
      codcl integer REFERENCES clienti(codcl))"

      DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE liniifact (nrfact integer REFERENCES facturi(nrfact),
      pozfact byte, codpr integer REFERENCES produse(codpr),
      cant integer, pret integer, PRIMARY KEY(nrfact,pozfact))"

    End Sub
```

When I run the code above, Access is saying that is an error in syntax an it is expecting alter, create table etc. I am running this code using a Create Query Design, and input field in the sql view, how am i suppose to run the code above to actually work, I need to run it somewhere else? and where? i need it in access to create a form using sql

Comment: which line is giving you the error, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use concatenation (`&`) and line continuations (`_`) if the string is to traverse onto a new line, e.g.:

```vb
Private Sub cmd_creare_Click()

    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE produse (codpr integer PRIMARY KEY, denpr text(30), " & _
    "stoc integer)"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE clienti (codcl integer, dencl text(30), " & _
    "PRIMARY KEY(codcl))"

    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE facturi (nrfact integer PRIMARY KEY, datfact date, " & _
    "codcl integer REFERENCES clienti(codcl))"

    DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE liniifact (nrfact integer REFERENCES facturi(nrfact), " & _
    "pozfact byte, codpr integer REFERENCES produse(codpr), " & _
    "cant integer, pret integer, PRIMARY KEY(nrfact,pozfact))"

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you may find it more readable to do this:

```vb
Private Sub cmd_creare_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "CREATE TABLE produse "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    codpr integer PRIMARY KEY, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    denpr text(30), "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    stoc integer "
    strSQL = strSQL & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "CREATE TABLE clienti "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    codcl integer, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    dencl text(30), "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    PRIMARY KEY(codcl) "
    strSQL = strSQL & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "CREATE TABLE facturi "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    nrfact integer PRIMARY KEY, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    datfact date, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    codcl integer REFERENCES clienti(codcl) "
    strSQL = strSQL & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "CREATE TABLE liniifact "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    nrfact integer REFERENCES facturi(nrfact), "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    pozfact byte, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    codpr integer REFERENCES produse(codpr), "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    cant integer, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    pret integer, "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    PRIMARY KEY(nrfact,pozfact) "
    strSQL = strSQL & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: @calinsirbu You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!